# How is the browser changing my textarea tag into a self closing tag?

Tags: php, html, textarea, google-chrome-devtools

In another Question I posted regarding an issue I'm having with a PHP page I'm working on a couple people commented telling me that I'm using the textarea tag as a self closing tag which is causing all my problems.  I know better than to do that so it got me double and tripple checking my coding and as I already expected, the tag is closed.  Here's a picture of it in Dreamweaver

[image]

So at first I had no clue as to what they were talking about, but upon inspecting it in the developer's tools in Chrome I seen this

[image]

So the browser is somehow taking it upon itself to change my textarea tag into a self closing tag. How is it doing this and how do I stop it?  So far to my knowledge it only does it to the textarea listed here.  There's more throughout the full version of my questionnaire and to my knowledge they all show up fine.  What is it about this one that's triggering this to happen?

/////////////////////////////////////UPDATE//////////////////////////////////

ok I right clicked and selected "view source" AND "inspect element" and it is indeed showing the textarea tag being rendered into a self closing tag.  The first picture I posted was the "inspect element" option, here's the "view source" option.

[image]

so yeah.....  somehow it's getting switched up on me and it's eating the rest of the PHP file all the way through to the closing HTML tag.  Thanks for all yoru help so far, hopefully we can get this figured out, it took me 3 days to figure out this is the problem, I was originally getting an error from my .js file saying the onclick function can't be null and my syntax was perfect.  It was coming back like that because this is swallowing up the element it attempted to refer to so there was nothing for it to apply itself to.

///////////////////////////////UPDATE 2/////////////////////////////////////

OK I used the Validator at W3.org as suggested and this is what it threw back

[image]

I took out the PHP data to prevent it from coming up as an error.  But this is how I have it in Dreamweaver.

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors','on'); ?><?php include('extlib/vdaemon/vdaemon.php'); ?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Oswald|Poiret+One&subset=latin,latin-ext,greek-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Files/css/Corp_ID_and_Branding_Questionnaire_2.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
</header>

<form action="core/process.php" method="post" id="CorpID" runat="vdaemon">

<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="Questionnaire" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://optiqvision.x10host.com/Corp_ID_and_Branding_Questionnaire.html" />

    <div id="page01">
        <div id="p_content">
        <div class="title02">
                Contact and Location
            </div><br /><br /><br /><!--Contact and Location-->

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="float:left; width:44%; height:66px;">
                    <label for="fname" class="label_01">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="First_Name" class="tex_inp01" style="font-size:16pt;" />

                </div>

                <div class="texfrm_i" style="float:right; width:44%; height:66px;">
                    <label for="lname" class="label_01">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="Last_Name" class="tex_inp01" style="font-size:16pt;" />

                </div>
            </div><!--texfrm--><br /><br />

           <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="margin:auto; width:66; height:66px;%">
                    <label for="email" class="label_01">E-Mail</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="E_Mail" class="tex_inp01" style="font-size:16pt;" />
                </div>
            </div><!--texfrm--><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="margin:auto; width:66%; height:66px;">
                    <label for="fbnam" class="label_01">Facebook Name...(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fbnam" name="FB_Name" class="tex_inp01" style="font-size:16pt;" />
                </div>
            </div><!--texfrm--><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="margin:auto; width:66%; height:66px;">
                    <label for="twnam" class="label_01">Twitter Name...(optional)</label>
                    <input type="text" id="twnam" name="Twitter_Name" class="tex_inp01" style="font-size:16pt;" />
                </div>
            </div><!--texfrm--><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:33%; float:left; height:66px;">
                    <label for="country_sel" class="label_01">Country</label>
                    <select id="country_sel" class="tex_inp01" name="Country" style="width:88%; font-size:12pt;">
                        <option selected value="Please select a Country">Please select a Country</option>
                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                        <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                        <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                        <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                        <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                        <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                        <option value="Bahamas, The">Bahamas, The</option>
                        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                        <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                        <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                        <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                        <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                        <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                        <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                        <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                        <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                        <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                        <option value="Burma">Burma</option>
                        <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                        <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                        <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                        <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                        <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                        <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                        <option value="China">China</option>
                        <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                        <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                        <option value="Congo, Democratic Republic of the">Congo, Democratic Republic of the</option>
                        <option value="Congo, Republic of the">Congo, Republic of the</option>
                        <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                        <option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
                        <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                        <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                        <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option>
                        <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                        <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                        <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                        <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                        <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                        <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                        <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                        <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                        <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                        <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                        <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                        <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                        <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                        <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                        <option value="France">France</option>
                        <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                        <option value="Gambia, The">Gambia, The</option>
                        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                        <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                        <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                        <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                        <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                        <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                        <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                        <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                        <option value="Holy See">Holy See</option>
                        <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                        <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                        <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                        <option value="India">India</option>
                        <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                        <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
                        <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                        <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                        <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                        <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                        <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                        <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                        <option value="Korea, North">Korea, North</option>
                        <option value="Korea, South">Korea, South</option>
                        <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
                        <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                        <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                        <option value="Laos">Laos</option>
                        <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                        <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                        <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                        <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                        <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
                        <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                        <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                        <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                        <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                        <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                        <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                        <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                        <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                        <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                        <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                        <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                        <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                        <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                        <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                        <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                        <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                        <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                        <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                        <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                        <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                        <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                        <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                        <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                        <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                        <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                        <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                        <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                        <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                        <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                        <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                        <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                        <option value="Palestinian Territories">Palestinian Territories</option>
                        <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                        <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                        <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                        <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                        <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                        <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                        <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                        <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
                        <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                        <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                        <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                        <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                        <option value="Samoa ">Samoa </option>
                        <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                        <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                        <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                        <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                        <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                        <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                        <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                        <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                        <option value="Sint Maarten">Sint Maarten</option>
                        <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                        <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                        <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                        <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                        <option value="South Korea">South Korea</option>
                        <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
                        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                        <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                        <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                        <option value="Swaziland ">Swaziland </option>
                        <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                        <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                        <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
                        <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                        <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                        <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
                        <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                        <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                        <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                        <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                        <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                        <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                        <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                        <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                        <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                        <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
                        <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                        <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                        <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                        <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                        <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                    </select><!--countries-->
                </div><!--texfrm_i-->

                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:33%; float:left; margin-left:3.3px; height:66px;">
                    <label for="st_prov" class="label_01">State/Province</label>
                    <input type="text" id="st_prov" class="tex_inp01" name="State/Province" style="width:88%; font-size:12pt;" />
                </div><!--texfrm_i-->

                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:33%; float:right; height:66px;">
                    <label for="city" class="label_01">City</label>
                    <input type="text" id="city" class="tex_inp01" name="City" style="width:88%; font-size:12pt;" />
                </div><!--texfrm_i-->

            </div><!--texfrm_o--><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:66px;">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:33%; margin:auto; height:66px;">
                    <label class="label_01">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" style="width:22%; float:left; margin-left:11px; font-size:16pt;" class="tex_inp01" />
                    <input type="text" maxlength="3" style="width:22%; float:left; margin-left:9px; font-size:16pt;" class="tex_inp01" />
                    <input type="text" maxlength="4" style="width:33%; float:right; margin-right:11px; font-size:16pt;" class="tex_inp01" />
                </div><!--texfrm_i-->
            </div><!--texfrm_o--><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o" style="height:160px">
                <div class="texfrm_i" style="width:66%; margin:auto; height:146px;">
                    <label for="my_comp" class="label_01">How did you hear about my Company?</label>
                    <textarea id="my_comp" class="tex_inp01" style="width:88%; height:100px; font-size:14pt;"></textarea>

                </div>
            </div><br /><br /><br />

            <div class="texfrm_o">
                <div class="button" id="p1_next" style="width:22%; height:40px; margin:auto;">
                    <div class="sub_title02">Next</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--p_content-->

        <div id="background"></div>
    </div><!--page01-->

</form>


<footer>
</footer>
<?php VDEnd(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.optiqvision.x10host.com/Files/Javascript/Corp_ID_and_Branding_Questionnaire.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also ran it through a PHP validator and got 0 errors.  I tried putting text between the textarea tags and that seemed to stop it from happening, but I had info inside of the textarea, I came across another post on here where they said to put >  in there, but I was able to see that too, plus I don't think whatever that is applies to anything I'm doing.

Does the errors and this coding help shed light on anything?

Comment: try running whole page through w3c validator. What is problem with textarea as a result?

Comment: What does dev tools show if you put text between the tags?

Comment: looking at page posted in prior question it has invalid markup between body and head

Comment: My guess is that somebody has some non-HTML-aware XML processing tool set up on your server that your HTML source is getting run through. And that tool is seeing the empty `<textarea ..></textarea>` and just simple-mindedly changing it to `<textarea />`, because it doesn’t understand that HTML documents can’t have that. Certainly no actual HTML parser is ever going to do change it in that way.

Comment: I ran the code through here
https://html5.validator.nu/

and no error came back with the textarea tag.

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq Maybe there’s some PHP plugin installed that’s causing it?

Comment: @DaMightyOptiq btw for  validation please consider using https://validator.w3.org/nu/ —which is the same backend but these days is kept much more up to date than https://html5.validator.nu/ (I am one of the co-maintainers for the source for both of them, and I sometimes push updates to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ almost daily; but I do not have access to https://html5.validator.nu/ to push updates there, and so these days it is sometimes months out of date from the latest changes and fixes.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker that is interesting because I tried running the url through w3 version and it did pick up the textarea. Haven't used that tool for several years...sort of miss the older output format

Comment: @sideshowbarker I ran it through and got nothing back in terms of the textarea.  I updated the post to show what I got and posted the entire code for that page.

Answer (score 4):

The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqwhk.jpg appears to not be from devtools at all but instead just from using **View source** in your browser. In which case, what it’s showing you is the actual HTML source that your own Web server is sending over the wire to browsers.

In other words, it’s not your browser that’s changing your `texarea` element to use a self-closing tag—instead, it’s something in your own Web server that’s doing that.

If you try right-clicking on the page and doing **Inspect Element** so that your browser devtools actually open, you’ll see that the devtools view is very different from what’s in your https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqwhk.jpg image.

For one thing, the devtools view has syntax highlighting, with multiple colors. Beyond that you’ll see that it doesn’t show your empty `textarea` element as `<textarea/>`. Instead it in fact shows it as `<textarea></textarea>`. Browser devtools never use self-closing tag syntax for anything.

Comment: I just right clicked and selected "view source" and "inspect element" and it does indeed show <textarea....../> and took away the closing tag.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I stumbled upon what was causing the problem.  From looking at the coding over and over so much I realized I forgot to give the textarea input a name like all the other inputs so I gave it one and continued scanning the code, eventually I uploaded it and and the problem was gone.  Just to be sure on what it was I deleted the name and tested it and the problem came back.

so I guess if a textarea in a PHP file doesn't have a name attribute it for some reason makes itself a self closing tag that gets ignored by the browser until it runs into the closing tag of another textarea WITH a name attribute.  If anyone can elaborate more on the mechanics of how this problem occurs from this action I'd appreciate more info on why it happens... as much of a headache as it gave me lol.  Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is completely normal behavior.

Developper Tools are showing you the "processed" HTML page, with all the changes to the DOM that some of your JavaScript scripts may be doing, for example, and also with the changes your browser appends to the page (form autocompletion, etc.)

So the code you see in Developper Tools will likely be different on every browser/plugin you try. You only see a representation of the DOM as the browser has interepreted it: your textarea being empty, it is interpreted the same way as a self-closing textarea.

Try a simple `CTRL+U` and you will see the real source code parsed by your browser without any changes. You will see that your textarea is not self-closing.

Anyway, it isn't a problem at all and your code behaves exactly the way it is supposed to, since it is **your** code that is parsed by the browser.

Comment: It is actually a problem if the HTML source has `<textarea />` rather than `<textarea></textarea>`. Because browsers ignore that slash and just treat a `<textarea />` tag exactly the same as a `<textarea>` tag. A start tag. Which means the source actually contains no end tag for the `textarea` element. And therefore, any other markup in the HTML source that follows that `<textarea>` tag becomes text content of the `textarea`; it will just eat up all the subsequent markup in the document, and completely break the intended behavior/rendering of the document.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I figured it was only a way for the Developper Tools plugin OP was using to shorten the code visually, but that the browser engine would have rendered the page according to the real source code (which I supposed to be right, according to the DreamWeaver screenshot), but you may be right!